# pgadmin4 is broken after update to version 4.11

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've been using pgadmin 4 successfully until I ran a Ubuntu 18.04 update, which had the update for pgadmin 4 included.  Now, whenever I run a 'Select * from table', instead of displaying the results, it displays 'table_oid'.  I googled this and there was mention of a .pgadmin.conf, which I cannot find on my system anywhere.  Also tried to uninstall/reinstall, which did not work.

Tried to uninstall/reinstall, tried manually creating the .pgadmin folder and the pgadmin.conf file, but this did not help.  I'm sure it's something simple, but it's confusing because of the different ways it can be installed, file locations, and all of that. My python version is 3.6.  Appreciate anything that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade the python3 package psycopg2 to version >= 2.8 (see [here](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/pgAdmin4-v-4-11-SELECT-returns-table-oid-td6096647.html)).

Comment: I uninstalled psycopg2 version 2.7 and installed psycopg2 version 2.8.3, however, pgadmin 4 still doesn't function properly.  pip3 freeze | grep psycopg2 command displays psycopg2==2.8.3 now rather than 2.7.  I also tried uninstalling pgamin4 and reinstalling it after I had upgraded psycopg2.  Is there some configuration for pgadmin4 that still needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Toobles for pointing me in the right direction.  I had found a post talking about the ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf file, but I did not have that file.  I created it and inserted the posted settings, but it still didn't work.  I just discovered that I only created the file and not pgadmin4 DIRECTORY.  So dumb.  To summarize the fix:

1. Upgrade the python3 package psycopg2 to version >= 2.8 (Toobles)
2. If required, create the ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf file and insert:

   [General]
   ApplicationPath=
   BrowserCommand=
   FixedPort=false
   PortNumber=1
   PythonPath=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed and pgAdmin4 has added backward compatibility with psycopg2 driver.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.12/release_notes_4_12.html